# Sorting columns in nested ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Currently I don't have any possibility to sort the columns of my list by using the `orderBy`-filter. The problem what I have is a nested ngRepeat.

View:

```
<md-list>
        <md-list-item>
            <span ng-repeat="item in ::hItems track by $index" ng-click="sortBy(item)" flex>
                {{ ::item }}
            </span>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="cItem in ::cItems | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse track by $index">
            <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::cItem track by $index" flex>
                {{ ::value }}
            </span>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

As soon as the user click on a column header the function `sortBy` will be invoked. The function is implemented in the controller as follows:

```
//Default values:
$scope.sortType = 'NAME';
$scope.sortReverse = false;
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');

//sortBy func:
function sortBy(columnKey) {
    $scope.sortType = columnKey;
    $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
    $scope.cItems = orderBy($scope.cItems, $scope.sortType, $scope.sortReverse);
}
```

The list sorts just by the default value `name`. Here is the array output of GET-request:

```
//JSON data
[
    {
        "ArtNo": "DE123",
        "SHORTCODE": "ABC",
        "NAME": "article one",
        "QUANTITY": 3,
        "GROUPID": 1,
        "ACTIVE": 1
    },...
]
```

So, I need nested ngRepeat because how you can see the array is defined with key numbers and object values => `[0:Object, 1:Object...]`. I need just a solution for my `sortBy`-function. Have anyone an idea?

The following is my output list:

```
ArtNo | SHORTCODE | NAME          | QUANTITY
DE123 |   ABC001  | article one   | 3
DE456 |   ABC002  | article two   | 8
DE789 |   ABC003  | article three | 4
DE321 |   ABC004  | article four  | 13
....
```

Comment: Please simplify your question code and provide a working fiddle...

Comment: @EliasSoares What don't you understand in my code? Then I can edit my thread.

Comment: What is `md-list`, `md-list-item`, `md-divider`? I know that this may not have influence in the problem, but when you provide the smallest code that the problem occurs, it's easy for you (and us) to find the problem.

Comment: @EliasSoares ouh ok. That are directives of Angular Material.

Comment: Why are you doing an orderBy inside your `sortBy` function?

Comment: @EliasSoares orderBy is the pre-defined filter of Angular. I need this filter to sort the corresponding column and getting back the new sorted content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128758/discussion-between-elias-soares-and-yuro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want this behavior:

- User click on desired column to sort, and the table content will be ordered by that column.
- User click again and the sort direction inverts.

Right?

So why are you ordering twice your array?

```
//Default values:
$scope.sortType = 'NAME';
$scope.sortReverse = false;
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');

//sortBy func:
function sortBy(columnKey) {
    $scope.sortType = columnKey;
    $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
    // You do not need to order anything here. Just define your orderby parameters here to be used on view.
}
```

## Real solution

As talk with question author, we did found the main problem here:

The use of `::` syntax on `ng-repeat` avoids angular from watching changes on `OrderBy` filter, so the change did not reflect on view.